# Definitions of normalisers for infinite groups

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, infinity, infinite-groups

If G is a group and A is a subset of G, the normaliser of A in G can be defined as either

(1) $N_G(A) = \{g \in G\ |\ gag^{-1} \in A, \forall a \in A\}$

(2) $N_G(A) = \{g \in G\ |\ gAg^{-1} = A \}$ where $gAg^{-1} = \{ gag^{-1}\ |\ \forall a \in A\}$

**I want to prove definition (1) $\implies$ definition (2)** i.e. that the sets defined in (1) and (2) are the same

If A is finite then the fact that $f_g: A \to A,\ a \mapsto gag^{-1}\ (g \in N_G(A))$ is an injective function implies that $f_g$ is bijective (since an injective map from a finite set to itself is bijective).

However an injective map from an infinite set to itself isn’t necessarily bijective. So my question how would one go about proving this in the case that A is infinite?

Comment: But what is $gAg^{-1}$?

Comment: See my edit @the_fox

Comment: Are you trying to prove that the set defined in (1) is contained in the set defined in (2)?

Comment: No I am trying to prove they are the same set @suchan

Answer (score 2, accepted):

(1) doesn't imply (2) (where by (1) and (2) I think you mean the condition such that an element of $G$ is in the subset)

Consider the following counterexample: $G=\Bbb{Q}\rtimes \Bbb{Q}^\times$
As a set we have $G=\Bbb{Q}\times\Bbb{Q}^\times$. The product is defined to be
$$(a,r)(b,s)=(a+br,rs).$$
Observe that this is a group since $(0,1)(b,s)=(b,s)=(b,s)(0,1)$, and $(a,r)\left(\frac{-a}{r},\frac{1}{r}\right)=(0,1)$.

We regard $\Bbb{Q}$ as a subgroup of $G$ by $q\mapsto (q,1)$. Now if $A=\Bbb{Z}\subseteq \Bbb{Q}\subseteq G$, $g=(0,2)$, then we have 
$$(0,2)(n,1)\left(0,\frac{1}{2}\right)=(2n,2)\left(0,\frac{1}{2}\right)=(2n,1),$$ 
so $$(0,2)\Bbb{Z}\left(0,\frac{1}{2}\right)=2\Bbb{Z}.$$ This is therefore a counterexample, since $gAg^{-1}\subseteq A$, but $gAg^{-1}\ne A$.

Comment: Does this mean that they aren’t equivalent definitions of the normalizer? If so what is the accepted definition?

Comment: @IsaacGreene The accepted definition is the second one. The first doesn't define a subgroup in general. In my example $(0,2)$ would be in the set, but $(0,1/2)$ would not.

Comment: Thanks for clearing that up. Are they equivalent when A is finite? Or is the argument I provided wrong? @jgon

Comment: @IsaacGreene They are equivalent when $A$ is finite. Your argument is correct

Comment: Thankyou very much for your answer @jgon